# Aggregated value from last 6 months in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic with messages in Kafka. Each message contains duration, resourceId and a list of tags.

In other part of the system I need to have for each pair resourceId and tag a value representing sum of all durations from messages (having that resourceId and tag) from the last 6 months. For each pair I'm only interested in the last value. It may be not the most up to date (for example: computed one day before is acceptable).

Is it something that could be aggregated in Kafka using Kafka Streams/KSQL or it's better to search for a solution outside Kafka? If it can be done in Kafka how to approach it?

Comment: It can be done using a sliding 6 month window, at the expense of disk usage, yes. What have you tried so far? If you have an external database available, that would be better, in my opinion

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but I have an external database and it was my option number 2 if Kafka is not the right place.

Comment: https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/windowing/

Comment: It is something I've checked before asking here. I'm not sure how to achieve what I need. The only option I've found is to use a hopping window with 6 months size and 1 day advance. However I am not sure about the performance implications - does it process 6 months of data every day?

Comment: Hopping window is "every 6 months". A sliding window is "last 6 months" or maybe I have terms mixed ... In any case, I don't know about performance as this will obviously need to write to disk for persistence/aggregation. Thus why an external database is more common for large range queries